# I have installed I3wm onto my Ubuntu 20.04 but I have no xsession file

Tags: 20.04, i3-wm

Here my screenshot and I just don't know what do I need to write to .desktop file because I suppose the cause it is.

[image]

Comment: You have to have a file with a arbitrary name like **i3.desktop** . The contents should be like [this](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/QF4b2k5HVY/) . That's mine. I think it might be a problem with the postint scripts that didn't configured that file for you.

Comment: Thank you, I need definitely this file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a file with the name **i3.desktop**(can be anything else , what is important is the **Name** property below) . The contents should be like this :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=i3
Comment=improved dynamic tiling window manager
Exec=i3
TryExec=i3
Type=Application
X-LightDM-DesktopName=i3
DesktopNames=i3
Keywords=tiling;wm;windowmanager;window;manager;
```

But this file is included in the package **i3-wm** and I think you haven't installed it correctly or it might be a problem with package dependencies.In **18.04** however installing **i3** would install some other packages including **i3-wm**.

```
$ dpkg-query -L i3-wm | grep i3\.desktop
/usr/share/applications/i3.desktop
/usr/share/xsessions/i3.desktop
```